# ngx-translate: createTranslateLoader method with custom path doesn't work when compiling as AOT

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, aot, ngx-translate

I'm currently trying to create an application with some i18n.
I'm using ngx-translate to translate my application.

Everything works until I try to edit the createTranslateLoader method to get my .json files from another folder.

Currently I have this (and works):

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http , './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But when I change ./assets/i18n/ to ./locale/i18n/  (Which is on the same level as assets and has the same contents as the locale/i18n/ folder) I get the following error:

> ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found",
>   url: "http://localhost:8910/locale/i18n/en.json", ok: false, name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8910/locale/i18n/en.json",
>   error: "

I'm compiling in AOT so I went and took a look at the dist folder after I've build. There I saw the compiled folder still has an 'Assets' folder with the i18n folder in it ( and the required json files).

So now it feels like there is no way to set the translateLoader to a custom folder when compiling as AOT, does anybody have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

In the .angular-cli.json file there is an 'assets' attribute. My understanding is that there you can add the folders that you want to create while compiling in AOT

```
 "assets": [
        "assets",
        "locale/i18n",   //Added this line
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

And now it works.